# Writing files on network shares with windows task scheduler with python

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

There might be the need to automate python scripts on windwos using the task scheduler. You can tackle this problem by installing Python on the Windows machine, or by freezing the script into an .exe-file, for example using pyinstaller.

However, there are some pitfalls using the task sceduler and they are really hard to debug, since you don't get and stdout and the script will behave diferently than when started manualy.

One of this problems is writing to network shares. When writing a file to a network share that is mapped to a drive, the script simply stops. You can find out the stopping position with try & error, print statements and logging, but the actual problem is not shown in the stdout.

**How can I write a file to a network share?** The following code fails:

```
my_file = "N:\my_folder\my_file.csv"

with open(my_file ,'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=';', lineterminator= '\r')
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem lies within the nature of the windows task scheduler and how windows handels user sessions and network shares. Network shares are a part of the user session, eg. they are created when a given user logs in.

The task scheduler **operates from outside of the user session, so it has no access to the mapping of network shares to drive letters.** Instead of using the drive letter you need to use the fully qualified domain name and UNC path to access the share.

Try the following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
my_file = Path(r'//192.168.1.123/my_share/my_folder/my_file.csv')    # When no DNS is availiable
my_file = Path(r'//computername/my_share/my_folder/my_file.csv')     # When using DNS

with open(my_file ,'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel', delimiter=';', lineterminator= '\r')
    writer.writerow(['Date', 'Value'])
```